# Drawing Nquvist-Plot i Simulink

Tags: matlab, plot, simulink

I build an equivalent circuit in Simulink and it works. Now I want to get the nquvist plot of this equivalent circuit. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this. Till now I only get the Impedance versus the frequency. I attached the equivalent circuit:

[image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

When using blocks from "Simscape Power Systems Specialized Technology" use voltage/current measurement blocks (depending on the numerator/denumerator of the transfer function). The outputs of these blocks are Simulink signals. Once you have the signals, you can use the "Simulink Control Design" toolbox to display a Nyquist plot directly. See [following link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/slcontrol/gs/bode-response-of-simulink-model.html) for an example (although for Bode plot, but it is straight forward to apply the procedure to Nyquist plots).